# AngularJS - "$digest already in progress" after logout

Tags: angularjs

I want to redirect to the main page after the user is logged out

```
$rootScope.logOut = function () {
   myService.logOut().then(function (data) {
      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
         $location.path("/");
      });
   });
}
```

but it generates

> $digest already in progress

error. How to fix it ?

Comment: why is `$apply()` there in the first place? That's what's triggering problem

Comment: the $digest il already running in your promise.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a $timeout

```
$rootScope.logOut = function () {
   myService.logOut().then(function (data) {
      $timeout(function(){
          $location.path("/");
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: `$timeout`  will already call `$apply` internally so need to remove `$apply`